# shell_exec curl to GraphQL API - Bad Request

Tags: php, curl, graphql

I'm trying play with a website's GraphQL API (`https://www.xxxlutz.hu/api/graphql`) to scrape data. In Altair working fine, but I need to run in PHP with `curl_impersonate` to bypass Cloudflare.

I tried this, and working fine:

[image]

```
$d = '{"query":"query {navigation(codes: [\"header_nav_root\"], levelAmount:2 , levelOffset:0){data}}"}';
$curl_impersonate_exec_command = '/usr/local/bin/curl_chrome100 -g -L  "' . $url . '" -X POST  -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d \'' . $d.' \'' ;
        
$response = shell_exec($curl_impersonate_exec_command);
        
echo $response;
```

I tried another query, but something wrong with my query string, maybe in "filters" param. I tried many ways, but I receive "bad request".

in Altair working fine, but in php curl don't ...
[altair](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jBoA.png)

Without filters, looks working fine, error message, "filters" missing. Ok.

```
$d = '{"query":"query {getSearchResults(cid: \"\",pagination: \"{page:1,numberOfResults:60}\", sortBy: \"available\"   ) {    rid  }}"}';
        
$curl_impersonate_exec_command = '/usr/local/bin/curl_chrome100 -g -L  "' . $url . '" -X POST  -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d \'' . $d.' \'' ;
        
$response = shell_exec($curl_impersonate_exec_command);
       
echo $response;
```

I'm tried to add filters, but I can't figure out the right syntax

```
 filters: "[{\"id\": \"categories\",\"type\": \"categoryFilter\",\"values\":[\"C1\",\"C1C9\",\"C1C9C1\"]}]",`
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Why are you doing this with `shell_exec()`? PHP has a built-in `curl` library.

Comment: Yes, i know, but the site cloudflare protected (xxxlutz.hu), and curl_impersonate can bypass this.